# How to properly pass array pointers to function in C

Tags: c, pointers, computer-science, user-defined-functions

A different question may have been asked about this program, however in this C code I have three functions: one to print records, one to add a record and one to delete a record.

What I don't understand is **why the (add) and (delete) do not make changes in the main function**, so when I use the `print all records` function it prints changes, but it doesn't show changes, what is wrong?

Details are in the comments, please feel free to run the code to visualise the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*The program is to store student record (firstname,lastname and score), it should not be more
than 15 records and the names should not be more than 20 chars, array pointersnare being used
instead of arrays, the (add_record) and (delete_record) functions must
do thsi change in the main function, so when you print all records, the changes are shown*/

void print_records(char **firstname,char **lastname,float *score,int *the_size)
{
    int i;
    printf("Printing All record(s)...\n");

    for (i=0;i<*the_size;i++) /*loop to print records of all arrays in correct format*/
    {
        printf("Firstname : %s, Lastname : %s, Score : %f\n",firstname[i],lastname[i],score[i]);

    }
}
void add_new_record (char **firstname,char **lastname,float *score,int the_size)
{
    printf("Add new record in the format :\nFirstname Lastname Score\n");
    /*the strategy here is to check if all 15 elemts are used, if they are, use realloc
    to add one more, if not add the record after the last record*/
    if (the_size == 15)
    {
        firstname=realloc(firstname,16*sizeof(char*));
        firstname[15]=malloc((20+1)*sizeof(char));
        lastname=realloc(lastname,16*sizeof(char*));
        lastname[15]=malloc((20+1)*sizeof(char));
        score=realloc(score,16*sizeof(float));
        scanf("%s %s %f",firstname[15],lastname[15],&score[15]);
        printf("New Record Added Successfully !\n");
        printf("Firstname : %s, Lastname : %s, Score : %f\n",firstname[15],lastname[15],score[15]);
    }
    else if (the_size<15)
    {
        scanf("%s %s %f",firstname[the_size],lastname[the_size],&score[the_size]);
        printf("New Record Added Successfully !\n");
        printf("Firstname : %s, Lastname : %s, Score : %f\n",firstname[the_size],lastname[the_size],score[the_size]);
    }
}
void delete_record (char **firstname,char **lastname,float *score,int the_size)
{
    char *str=malloc(20*sizeof(char)); /*String entered by user must be 20 or less chars*/
    int i,ctr=0;
    char *temp_first=malloc(20*sizeof(char));/*temp array to swap firstname must be 20 or less chars*/
    char *temp_last=malloc(20*sizeof(char)); /*temp array to swap lastname must be 20 or less chars*/
    float temp_score;/*ctr is the counter used to check if there are no matchs in the end*/
    printf("Enter the lastname of record(s) to delete : ");
    scanf("%s",str);
    /* the strategy here is to move the element to be deleted to the last index and use
    relloc to shrink the size by 1 (-1) */
    for (i=0;i< the_size;i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(str,lastname[i])==0)
        {
            printf("Deleting Record for %s %s...\n",firstname[i],lastname[i]);
            temp_score=score[i];
            score[i]=score[the_size-1];
            score[the_size-1]=temp_score;
            strcpy(temp_first, firstname[i]);  /*using strcpy function to swap strings*/
            strcpy(firstname[i], firstname[the_size-1]);
            strcpy(firstname[the_size-1], temp_first);
            strcpy(temp_last, lastname[i]);
            strcpy(lastname[i], lastname[the_size-1]);
            strcpy(lastname[the_size-1], temp_last);
            score=realloc(score,(the_size-1)*sizeof(float));
            firstname=realloc(firstname,(the_size-1)*sizeof(char*));
            lastname=realloc(lastname,(the_size-1)*sizeof(char*));
            ctr++;
            the_size--;


            }

        }
    if (!ctr) /*if ctr=0 (no increment), then print,there is no match*/
    {
        printf ("Sorry, no available record for %s",str);
    }
        free(temp_first);
        free(temp_last);
        free(str);
}
void main()
{
    char **firstname;
    char **lastname;
    float *score;
    int number_of_records,i,j=-1,ctr=1,row=15,col=20;
    /*ctr is to keep track of the student's number (makes it easier to
      the user), it starts with (1)*/

    firstname=malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        firstname[i]=malloc((col+1)*sizeof(char));
    }
     lastname=malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        lastname[i]=malloc((col+1)*sizeof(char));
    }
    printf("\nPlease indicate number of records you want to enter (min 2, max 15): ");
    scanf("%d",&number_of_records);
    score=malloc(row*sizeof(float));

    printf("\nPlease input records of students\n(enter a new line after"
           "each record), with following format:\nfirst name last name score ");
    for (i=0;i<number_of_records;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter record for student %d : ",ctr);
        scanf("%s %s %f",firstname[i],lastname[i],&score[i]);

        ctr++; /*ctr is to keep track of student number
                 (makes it easy to the user) */

    }


    while (j!=0) /*Main menu will keep looping after using a function as long as j is not 0
           When the user enters 0 (zero) the loop will stop and therefore the program will terminate*/
    {
        printf("\nSelect desired function by pressing the corresponding key number\n");

        printf("\n********** Main Menu **********\n");

        printf("\n>>> Print records (press 1)\n");

        printf("\n>>> Add a new Record (press 2 )\n");

        printf("\n>>> delete record (press 3)\n");


        printf("\n>>> Exit the program (press 0)\n");

        scanf("%d",&j); /*getting j from the user (j is used for selection and for the while loop)*/
        if (j==1)
        {
            print_records(firstname,lastname,score,&number_of_records);
        }
        else if (j==2)
        {
        add_new_record(firstname,lastname,score,number_of_records);
        }
        else if (j==3)
        {
    delete_record(firstname,lastname,score,number_of_records);
        }
    else if (j==0)
    {
    printf("Exitting program ...\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check that `malloc()` doesn't return `NULL`, always check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers have observed, in C, all arguments are passed by value.  That means the function gets a *copy* of the caller's value, therefore changes to that value are not visible to the caller.  In other words, given

```
void f(any_type arg) {
    arg = any_value;
}
```

The caller will never detect any change, regardless of what type `any_type` is or what value `any_value` is.  Note carefully, however, the difference between that, and this:

```
void f(any_type *arg) {
    *arg = any_value;
}
```

In that case, it is not the function argument (a pointer) that is being modified, it is the thing pointed to.  The argument is a copy of the caller's value, so *the two point to the same thing*.  The caller cannot detect changes to the argument, but after the call, it *can* detect changes to the thing it points to.

Your code exhibits some issues of this type, some of them responsible for your main problems.  Most importantly, these have to do with your record keeping on the number of elements in your list (variable `number_of_records` in `main()`).  Your addition and deletion functions work more or less ok, except that they cannot communicate the revised list size back to main.

There are additional issues in `add_new_record()` when there are already 15 records; if you can, I would just disallow that case.  If you must support it, then you have multiple things to clean up.  Some of them to do with pass-by-value issues, others to do with what your code should do when the list initially contains **16** or more records.

**Update**:
Since you're having so much trouble working this out, here's a revised version of `delete_record()`.  It implements a lot more than the minimal changes required to get the desired output upon record deletion, as there was in fact a goodly number of other issues that I might as well call out as long as I'm going to the trouble.  See new and modified comments.

```
/*
 * Can realloc() *firstname, *lastname, and *score and return the updated
 * values to the caller.  Most importantly, can update *the_size and have
 * the caller see the result.
 */
void delete_record (char ***firstname, char ***lastname, float **score, int *the_size)
{
    int i;
    int initial_size = *the_size;
    char str[21];  /* no need to malloc a fixed-length local array */

    printf("Enter the lastname of record(s) to delete : ");
    fflush(stdout);  /* The prompt might not appear if you don't flush */
    /*
     * Note the field width in the format below.  Without it, a user can
     * easily cause a buffer overflow.
     */
    scanf("%20s", str);

    /*
     * The strategy for each element to delete (there may be more than one)
     * is to free the element's name components (else their allocated memory
     * leaks), copy the last (at that time) element's components into
     * place (for the name components, just the pointers), and later
     * realloc to shrink the overall size to exactly fit the remaining
     * elements (once we know how many that is).
     */
    for (i = 0; i < *the_size; )
    {
        if (strcmp(str, (*lastname)[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Deleting Record for %s %s...\n", (*firstname)[i], (*lastname)[i]);
            free((*firstname)[i]);
            free((*lastname)[i]);
            (*firstname)[i] = (*firstname)[*the_size - 1];
            (*lastname)[i] = (*lastname)[*the_size - 1];
            (*score)[i] = (*score)[*the_size - 1];
            *the_size -= 1; /* not the same as *the_size-- */
            /* don't increment i, else we miss testing the new i'th element */
        } else {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    if (*the_size != initial_size)
    {
        void *temp;

        /*
         * Always check the return value of realloc(), even when you're
         * shrinking the allocation.  Usually, though, you'd want at least
         * some kind of diagnostic in the event of failure.
         */
        temp = realloc(*firstname, sizeof(char *) * (*the_size));
        if (temp)
        {
            *firstname = temp;
        }
        temp = realloc(*lastname, sizeof(char *) * (*the_size));
        if (temp)
        {
            *lastname = temp;
        }
        temp = realloc(*score, sizeof(float) * (*the_size));
        if (temp)
        {
            *score = temp;
        }
    }
    else  /* there is no match */
    {
        printf ("Sorry, no available record for %s",str);
    }
}
```

Your `main()` would call that like so:

```
delete_record(&firstname, &lastname, &score, &number_of_records);
```

Similar changes are needed to `add_record()`, though you do have the separate issue I already called out there with increasing the number of entries past 16.

Additionally, you're making extra work for yourself by using separate arrays of first name, last name, and score.  It would be much easier to define a `struct` encompassing all three, and use just one dynamic array whose elements are instances of that `struct`.

Comment: with the presence of 2D arrays, it mkes the problem little more complex, makes me first assume that I passed the arrays correctly as pointers, I now know that there is a problem with number_of_records , but how do i access the elements of firstname and lastname in the function in order to reallocate them ?

Comment: You don't have 2D arrays, you have (dynamic) arrays of pointers (to allocated storage).  It does not in any case change anything.  The `any_type` in my comments can be literally *any* type, including pointer types.  You can and do successfully manipulate the elements of those arrays in your functions `add_new_record()` and `delete_record()`, in such a way that the changes are visible in `main()`.  You could likewise reallocate them, too, because your functions access the pointers via *pointers* to them.

Comment: The only reallocation problem in your code occurs when you want to expand the list to accommodate more elements, which I alluded to in my answer.  If you must support that functionality then again, the same rule applies.  In particular, if you have a variable of type `char **`, and you want to pass it to a function in such a way that the function can modify the caller's value, then you must pass a *pointer* to it.  In this case, the type of such a pointer would be `char ***`.

Comment: I didn't think of that, I'll try doing that.

Comment: That didn't change anything in the output.

Comment: I have no idea what, specifically, "that" is, but your code works for me after I make a few small changes, mostly, as I said, related to the variables and function arguments used to track the number of elements in the list.

Comment: Can you please give me the changes which made it work or the code after making these changes ?

Comment: I will post some code as an update shortly.  In the meantime, one possible gotcha: because of operator precedence, `*the_size--` does not mean the same thing as `(*the_size)--` or `*the_size -= 1`.

Comment: Update posted.  What I posted works for me, but I left some work for you to do yourself.

Comment: By the way, stop being so stingy with spaces.  They make code more readable, and we have an infinite supply.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're declaring the arguments of `add_` as pointers (presumably because you want the function to change the value of the variables whose addresses you pass):

```
add_new_record (char **firstname, char **lastname, float *score, int the_size) {
```

But then you simply assign the locals, not the things they point to:

```
    firstname = realloc(firstname,16*sizeof(char*));
    score = realloc(score,16*sizeof(float));
```

If you want to change the variables to which these point, you have to
dereference them for assignment:

```
    *firstname = malloc(16);
    *score = 1.0;
```

Now the original firstname pointer points to a valid chunk of memory (presumably you'll want to `strcpy()` some actual name there), and the original float variable to which score points is now 1.0.

There are other problems, but that's the primary reason this function doesn't change what you think it should, because you didn't tell it to.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a problem with pointers and pass-by-value, but the particular code you called out is only an issue in certain cases.  The same function also fails in cases that don't exercise that code at all.

Comment: Yes, I figured the problem is about passing pointers, But, haven’t I passed them arrays correctly ? given that they are pointer arrays originally, and for your third code, how  Do i access the elements of firstname in order to dynamically allocate them?